Why metallic part of a window rusted? How to fix it and prevent it in the future?
My apartment has 4 windows of the same size and same conditions, and only one of them has this problem. This is a window of 2m x 1m that opens to balcony with no shed, i.e. direct sun and rain could hit it.

This image is the base of the window, and what I have marked as 1 rusted very quickly, like in two weeks or so.
Questions:

Why is it rusted? My suspicion is that the damaged rubber (3 for example is the cause of it), however:

Why this window only and not the others? (maybe they have a better rubber part?!)
The number 2 is a whole I guess for water drainage, but still could allow humid to get it by design right?


I should change the rusted part, but how to get the screws open?
How to prevent it in the future?

Some info:

I live the north west of Germany, so it always rain, no matter which time of the year we are in
We moved into this apartment 1.5 years ago, but I did not notice this last year.

Please do let me know if I have missed anything, and thanks in advance!

Well, we know why it rusted.  Because it's steel, and there was water on it at some point—likely a while.  Can you provide photos with more context, and showing inside and outside?

I assume that the picture has been rotated and that we are looking at the bottom left corner of the window frame, since there is a portion of another window at the top left of the picture.

The gasket around the perimeter of the window frame and possibly the sash as well needs to be replaced.
The steel stop should be replaced with an injection molded type similar in style to shown in the top right of the picture. The injection molded types are made of zinc and do not rust. The one you have on there now did not come from the same hardware manufacturer. You can remove the screws with a properly sized screwdriver seated squarely into the head and twisting out while maintaining hand pressure on the handle end of the screwdriver to ensure that the tip does not pivot out of the screw.
The window needs to be adjusted so that it seals properly. There is evidence of  water and rust stains on the interior frame, therefore there is air (and water) passing through the entire window frame assembly. The drainage slot should be there but there should also be a corresponding plastic drainage cap on the exterior to deflect air from that slot.

You will need a 5mm(?) hex key. Around the perimeter of the sash are a series of studs with a corresponding head for the key. These studs are offset so that when rotated, they move closer or farther from the corresponding stop when the window  is locked. Start with one point of contact between the frame and the sash, make an adjustment and check by fully locking the window and seeing if the amount of force remains moderate while pulling the sash closer to the frame. Once you are satisfied, move on to the next adjustment point and repeat until the entire perimeter is inspected and adjusted. Or hire a professional.
